# How to authenticate a developer for YouTube video/channel by the owner?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, gdata

I am developing software for some YouTube channels not owned by myself.

To retrieve insight data, I need to be authenticated. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OAuth 2.0 for installed application: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OAuth2_Installed_Applications_Flow

First, register the API to get a client_id.

Then, ask the partner to log into their google account, type the following URL, change the client_id with yours. redirect_uri should be set to "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline

Then they authorize you application and get an authorization code.

Then open a terminal and type (change your code, client_id, and client_secret):

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code"
```

You will get response like:

`{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZTtm7SuokEB-RGtbBty9IIlNiP9-eNMMQKtXdMP3sfjL1Fc",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/HKSmLFXzqP0leUihZp2xUt3-5wkU7Gmu2Os_eBnzw74"
}`

Remember the refresh_token, and every time you run your application, you need to get a new access_token with the refresh_token.